# Tea Commerce + Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-teacommerce

I have an existing Umbraco site. I would like to add the option where users could buy a product and then pay for it etc.

Reading around it seems TeaCommerce (http://www.teacommerce.net/en/products/tea-commerce-starter-kit.aspx) is a module that can be used to achieve this.

So i download it and install it. All seems to install fine but now reading all the documentation that there is nothing states what to do next or how to proceed.

I then download the starter kit. Follow the instructions (http://www.teacommerce.net/media/11341/installation_guide.pdf) and the starter kit doesnt exactly run perfectly so i cant get the idea of how everything runs.

When i say the starter kit isnt running by that i mean i get the below errors

`Error loading Razor Script /general/meta-description.cshtml
'string' does not contain a definition for 'mediaItem'`

`Error loading Razor Script /cart/mini-cart.cshtml
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

I realised there was no Template associated with the site - so adding a template allowed the above page to load but with the errors stated.

From this point on could anyone guide me or point me to a working solution that i can replicate myself or how to integrate it with my existing Umbraco site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used teacommerce but can recommend uCommerce http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/ucommerce its free and you even get a razor shop fully built that you can just tweek to your need.So far this is the easiest commerce product on umbraco in my option.

Comment: How can you justify 350 euro once off vs 2500 euro per year?! what is so great about ucommerece that you cant get anywhere?

Comment: I don't only used the free version obviously and even that is still too complex for a simple shop. If your site is in v7 then try http://our.umbraco.org/projects/collaboration/merchello supposed to be free am still experimenting with it.

Comment: Depends on what you need the ecommerce system to do and the quality of support you need. We've had a one-on-one demo with the creator of uCommerce with our client. That's how you justify it @activebiz

Comment: I know this is an old thread but for the record we just created our module which fits in. The products were expensive and i noticed lack of support on the Umbraco forums which we couldnt risk taking.

Comment: so if you want a very basic shop functionality i created a package for umbraco just for that try https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/simplest-store/

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many ecommerce packages teacommerce doesn't have a built in product catalogue - so you have to build a catalogue in the Umbraco node structure - or use the "product information extractor" to use a catalogue in an XML file or accessed through an API.

I would assume that you're setting up with the node structure for the catalogue - so either you haven't built any 'Product' nodes yet or one of the fields (mediaitem) in the 'Product' node can't be accessed via /general/meta-description.cshtml which is a razor script file.  So debug the /general/meta-description.cshtml file where you see references to the mediaitem field and you should pick out the issue.

ucommerce is an alternative and is much more fully featured but its pricing model of annual charges for features like the marketing section (which allows you to build in discounting) should be considered and could cost thousands of euros per year - teacommerce costs hundreds of euros but is a one-off charge.